# Add tags for sequencing, sequence analysis or TraMineR?

Tags: discussion, tags, r

I'm currently starting an online course for social sequence analysis using the R package TraMineR. We plan to use stats.stackexchange.com to support the course and the evolving social sequence analysis community. However, as of now there is no tag for either sequencing, sequence-analysis, or traminer.

Would it be suitable to add these tags? If so, can anyone with enough reputation add these tags?

For more information about the course:
http://www.orgdna.net/traminer/

For more information about the R package TraMineR:
http://mephisto.unige.ch/traminer/

Comment: Our choice of CV was inspired by Google, that use SO for many of their products, including BigQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537591/google-bigquery

Our ambition is to create an open knowledge repository on CV that will help scholars and practitioners interested in R, social sequence analysis, and TraMineR.

If we were to use a mailing list, the knowledge we create during the course would be walled off, and we wanted to create access to knowledge about TraMineR to a wider audience.

Comment: Hi @Aron, I'd be glad to create these tags but, from what I can tell, there aren't any questions that they would suit right now. I don't think a tag can exist if it doesn't have any questions associated with it. Have you noticed any questions that would be appropriate candidates for any of these tags? If so, can you edit your post with links to them? If not, as whuber alludes to, the tag could just be created when such questions do arise.

Comment: Aron, I would like to echo @Macro's helpful comment: if there already exist some questions that need such tags, we would be happy to create them retroactively.  I am still hoping, as per my reply, that this is something that you will be able to take care of yourself as new questions are asked and, more importantly, will be able to manage in a natural, meaningful way in the future.

Comment: Since I don't have 300 in reputation, I can't create these tags. I'm referring to three questions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29901/how-to-describe-multi-channel-sequence-objects-in-traminer/29915#29915 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959811/displaying-traminer-r-dendrograms-in-text-table-format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873279/pivoting-a-csv-file-using-r

Comment: @AronLindberg, re: the question you linked to that is on the stats stackexchange, there already is a tag called [tag:sequential-analysis]  and it has been used there. Doesn't that cover the same ground that would be covered by `sequence-analysis`? Regarding the questions on stackoverflow, you may request there that someone create a `TraMineR` tag but, as you may know, pure programming questions are off topic here. If `TraMineR` comes up in the context of a statistical question here then it may be relevant to create that tag here at that time.

Comment: Thanks Macro. However, sequential analysis and sequence analysis are very different. The former stems from quality control research and the latter stems from genetic sequencing. So these tags would definitely need to be different. Also, many of the questions seem to straddle the programming/statistics boundary, see fx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959811/displaying-traminer-r-dendrograms-in-text-table-format that was migrated

Comment: @Aron, thank you for making the distinction. But, looking at [this page](http://mephisto.unige.ch/traminer/) about `TraMineR`, the ambiguity persists, as it seems to describe sequential analysis but says 'sequence analysis' in the heading. Also, I'd say that the stats SE question you linked to is borderline migration-worthy as it seems like a pure programming question. But, I'll step aside now and let someone who knows more about sequence analysis continue the convo.

Comment: @Aron Two of the three threads you link to are on SO; we cannot help you create tags there.  Consider flagging one of those threads with a request to create a suitable tag.  You could link to this thread for support.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are added at the time a question is asked and, on occasion, when an answer suggests a tag.  AFAIK, the original proposer (OP) of a question can add whatever new tag they need (although the site strongly encourages using existing tags when they suffice).  In this fashion tags develop organically to reflect the interests of the site's users.  If a subcommunity of users interested in a particular topic appears, appropriate tags ought to emerge automatically from the questions they ask and the answers that are given.

#### Edit

Comments indicate a user needs 300+ reputation to create a new tag.  I have therefore created tags for `sequence-analysis` and `traminer` and wrote wiki entries to distinguish `sequence-analysis` from `sequential-analysis`.

A good method for low-rep users to create tags is to flag their questions for moderator attention: the flagging dialog allows a couple hundred characters to make a request.  Another method is to start a new thread here in meta, but IMHO that's best when the tag might need community discussion.

Low-rep and new users can also provisionally edit tag wikis themselves: those will be reviewed by higher-rep users or moderators for approval.  Because even the highest-rep users will not necessarily have the knowledge to write wikis, we welcome and encourage people to write and edit wikis for subjects in which they have expert knowledge.

Comment: Hi @whuber - don't you need [300 rep](http://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) to create a tag? Or does this not apply when you originate the question?

Comment: @Macro I'm not sure and I have no way of testing (short of posting some kind of throw-away message on another site, which I wasn't inclined to do: but I was able to get as far as typing in a title, question, and new tag on another site and it didn't complain).

Comment: Yes, you need 300 in order to create these tags. This is part of the reason I'm asking, since I can't create the tags myself.

Comment: @whuber, you can find a list of CV's privileges & associated rep requirements [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges). When you check, it won't seem very informative, b/c it will say that you already have them (the max is 20k), however if you mouseover, or click on them you will be able to see the rep requirement. On another note, I'd like to say thank you for creating a tag wiki excerpt when you created the tags. I think that's a big deal & wish everyone would do so.

Comment: Thanks, @gung. I indeed consulted that list (and some other lists) before answering. Unfortunately it is incomplete and, in the case of tag creation, it is vague (because it does not say whether or not the OP can create a tag regardless of their reputation). I also consulted with the SE team and other mods yesterday to find out whether there are straightforward ways to test the site out, but there are not. So we just have to muddle through...